# constant dollar Gamma for variance swap

Tags: variance, gamma

Here is the result of Gamma for Variance swap. I think $S_t$ is the only variable in $\sigma^2_{Exected,t}.$ Then how could we get the presentation of Gamma:
$$\dfrac{1}{S_t^2},$$
there should be some $S_t$ terms in numerator.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That’s the formula for unit gamma. The dollar gamma formula (the objective that the variance swap is trying to create as constant) is given by: $$\Gamma * S^2$$  so the numerator contains the $S^2$ term to cancel the denominator.